# Get value in controller of awesome-rating library

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im using awesome Rating angularjs library
https://github.com/bandraszyk/awesome-rating
I would like to know how to get the selected value and put into my controller.
I receive undefined value with this $scope.rating

**controller:**

```js
app.controller('appctrl', function($scope, $http) {


$scope.optionst2 = {
    values : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
};


$scope.getratingvalue = function () {
    console.log($scope.rating)
};

};
```

**html:**

```html
 <div class="awesomeRating" awesome-rating="rating" awesome-rating-options="optionst2" ng-click="getratingvalue()"></div>
 <div class="awesomeRatingValue">
  <span class="awesomeRatingValue" ng-bind="'Rating value: ' + rating"></span>
 </div>
{{rating}}
```

I found a solution and it work perfectly, but it's maybe not the best way to this aha.

```js
 <div class="awesomeRating" awesome-rating="rating" awesome-rating-options="optionst2" ng-click="getratingvalue()"></div>
<span style="display: none;" id="getvall" ng-bind="rating" ng-value="rating" value="rating" ></span>
```

```js
$scope.rating = "D";
$scope.optionst2 = {
    values : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
};


$scope.getratingvalue = function () {
    setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
console.log($("#getvall").val())
  }, 50);
};
```

Comment: whos fire `getratingvalue` function??... if the `$scope.rating` isnt initializated then got undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try initialize `$scope.rating = "D";` first in the controller and then
execute the

```
$scope.getratingvalue = function () {
    console.log($scope.rating)
};
```

and then try select another rating and call again the `getratingvalue` function.

**UPDATE**
avoid the ng-click inside the directive.
better put a button apart. and the put the ng-click ex:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getratingvalue()">
```

also in below put this

```
<pre>{{rating}}</pre>
```

to see if you select some of the ratings it changes value.

**UPDATE 2**
im enlist in this [plnkr example](https://embed.plnkr.co/I5IJ5XoZytHLMpS4RiDa/)
the way it should work. try to compare both codes. hope helps.

Comment: try this... delete ng-click from the div.  and put in some other button. and put a pre with the ragint valu check my update answer.

Comment: I tried your solution but When you select a star and click on the button, the text change but in the console.log the value is D again on each new click or new selected value

Comment: try the plnkr i made

Comment: it works. we don't have to put in the main ctroller , you have to put the function in the sub controller., that's why it didn't worked ^^ I use another better lib for now but thanks !